# why doesnt netbeans support python and django?

Tags: python, ruby, ide, netbeans

i wonder why sun doesnt support python and django in netbeans?

cause i am choosing between learning ruby/rails or python/django.

does this mean that i should use ruby/rails cause then support comes out of the box?

seems that other applications favor support for ruby over python.

Comment: http://netbeans.org/features/python/index.html

Comment: I have been enjoying PyCharm - beta product from the JetBrains team http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why let one particular IDE determine what programming language you learn?

I use python a lot, and [Geany](http://www.geany.org/) does what I need rather well.  Other folks like heavier weight editors.  Here's a list to get you started:

[What IDE to use for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python)

Comment: You are correct, great programmers never depends on IDE. But if Great IDE available that increases productivity

Answer (score 6):

Netbeans now suports python please take look at http://wiki.netbeans.org/Python and DJANGO http://wiki.netbeans.org/Python70Roadmap

Comment: It is kind of funny/sad that the answer to the original issue (why don't they support Python) might not score as high as the meta response of why let your IDE choose your language.

Comment: It's pretty common, actually.  As a community of people trying to help one another, we often try to bring more information to the table than just a minimal answer.  We're not all in it purely to score reputation points, after all.

Comment: Besides, the original post contains two questions.  :)